# Can systemd version be upgraded to v240 or higher on Centos 7?

Tags: centos7, systemd

Currentl I'm facing an issue where I would like to redirect stdout/stderr to specific log files. I have a created a service file for `systemd` service where I have added the steps for redirection, which is not working because current version 219 of `systemd` on the system does not support it and would require v240+ to work. My machine is CentOS 7.7.

```
Service file:
=============
[Unit]
Description=Process Monitoring and Control Daemon
After=rc-local.service nss-user-lookup.target

[Service]
User=jams
#Type=forking
WorkingDirectory=/opt/workspace/Dashboard/source-code/dashboard/
ExecStart=/opt/workspace/.env/bin/python kafka_consumer.py
StandardOutput=append:/data/dashboard/access.log
StandardError=append:/data/dashboard/error.log
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target


$ systemctl --version
systemd 219
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA -APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 -SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN

$ cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 (Core)
```

Sorry, I'm not much familiar and have very less knowledge about this. Is it possible to upgrade the version of `systemd` to v240 or higher on CentOS 7.7 ? If yes, could anyone please point me in the right direction to get the source code and with the steps to build the package ?

Or, any alternatives ?

Answer (score 1):

I see the question is rather old, but if you are still searching for a solution then something like this could work:

```
ExecStart=/opt/workspace/.env/bin/python kafka_consumer.py >> /data/dashboard/access.log 2>>/data/dashboard/error.log
```

A similar solution works for me for a similar problem on CentOS 7 with systemd 219.

Comment: This suggestion is not working, because the arguments in `ExecStart=` are *not* run on a shell, but passed to `execve(3)`; see § [Command lines](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Command%20lines): “This syntax is inspired by shell syntax, but only the meta-characters and expansions described in the following paragraphs are understood, and the expansion of variables is different. Specifically, redirection using "<", "<<", ">", and ">>", pipes using "|", running programs in the background using "&", and other elements of shell syntax are not supported.“

Comment: Well, you're right, I overlooked my working solution, Try with:

ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "exec /opt/workspace/.env/bin/python kafka_consumer.py >> /data/dashboard/access.log 2>>/data/dashboard/error.log"